# Increment by 2 for n rows, increment by 4 once and repeat when referencing data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

thank you for taking the time to look at this question.

I'm looking for an equation that can easily take the numerical values from Sheet 1 (the first picture) which has 2 blank cells in between values for four values and then has 4 blank cells and then the other four values. I'm not sure if I am making sense but hopefully the picture I have attached helps.
Notice **2 blank rows** between first 4 rows with values (Rows 2-11) and same between rows 16 and 25.
Also notice the 4 blank rows between the two sets of values.

For me, this is repeated for 700 values, same set up of 2 blank rows for 4 sets of values and then 4 blank rows and then four sets of values with 2 blank rows. I'm sure there is an easier way to do this.

I'm trying to recreate Sheet 2 from Sheet 1 using an equation. Is this possible?

Apologies in advance, English isn't my first language.

[image: Sheet 1]
[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: Just to keep things clear, you may have '*two blank rows*' then '*four blank rows*' but you are **incrementing** by **three rows** and **five rows**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the numbers are going to start in B2 and the intervals and offset staggers are static then,

```
=INDEX(B:B, 2+(ROW(1:1)-1)*3+INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)*2)
```

If the first number is in S6 then,

```
=INDEX(S:S, 6+(ROW(1:1)-1)*3+INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)*2)
```

[image]

Comment: Too much math for a Monday morning.

Comment: At least I didn't have to invent 23 dimensions just to make the `#DIV/0!` math come out correctly.

Comment: @Jeeped You mentioned "if the numbers starts in B2". Where have you used that in the equation? I see the B but where is the 2? In my sheet, it starts from S6. How would I modify the equation?

Comment: `INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)+1)*2`. It just happens that you start in row 2 and every fourth increment is an additional 2 rows so I put the two together. If you started on a different row then this would be different but 1. that is just a grade school maths adjustment and 2. that is not what you asked in the original question.

Comment: @Jeeped I'm sorry but I don't think I understand completely. I get how to shift from column B to column S of another sheet but how do shift from row 2 to row 6? Please do help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What part of `<start row>+<3 times each additional row>+<2 times each additional four cycles>` is hard to understand? This is grade school maths. What is your best attempt so far?

Comment: @Jeeped `=INDEX('Sheet1'!S:S,(ROW('Sheet1'!1:1)-1)*3+(INT((ROW('Sheet1'!1:1)-1)/8)+6)*2)` where S is the column from other sheet, 8 is the number of values before the 4 blank cells, 6 is the starting row. Is this right?

Comment: You almost had it. Thanks for showing original effort. I've posted my own variation (there are multiple ways to do this) above.

Comment: @Jeeped You're the best. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Put this in D2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet1!A:A)))/(Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet1!A:A))<>""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

And copy down till you get blanks.

This will return the numbers in order that they appear on sheet 1.

The `Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet1!A:A))` set the data set bounds.  This being an array type formula it needs to reference the smallest possible data set.  This part finds the last cell in Column A and sets that as the extent of the data set so we do not do unnecessary iterations.

The MATCH part will return the last row that has text in it, if Column A has numbers then we need to change the `"ZZZ"` to `1E+99` to get the last row in column A with a number.

The AGGREGATE is working like a small in that it will create an array of row numbers and Errors.  It will return ROW Numbers where `(Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet1!A:A))<>"")` return true.  And an Error where it returns FALSE.

The second criterion `6` in Aggregate tells it to ignore the errors, so it is only looking at the returned row numbers.

The `ROW(1:1)` is a counter.  As the formula is dragged down it will iterate to 2 then 3 and so on.  This tells the Aggregate that you want the 1st then the 2nd then the 3rd and so on.

The chosen row number is then passed to the INDEX and the correct value is returned.

[image]

---

If your numbers are in order (smallest to largest like your example) or you want the output in order(smallest to largest) then you can use this simple equation in D2:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(Sheet1!B:B,ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Then copy down till you get blanks.

Comment: If you don't mind, sir, could you please explain this equation? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another formula you might use.

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((INT((ROW()-ROW($A$2))/4)*14+ROW(A$2))+(MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$2),4)*3),COLUMN($A$2),1,1,"Sheet1"))`

You can paste it to the first cell where you want the result and copy down.

Note that $A$2 is the cell from where all the counting starts. If your data start from A3 you can change the references accordingly. Note further that `ROW($A$2)` is long for `2`. I chose this syntax to enable you to identify the meaning.

`COLUMN($A$2)`, on the other hand, just identifies Column A as the source of the data to be lifted. Row 2 in this formula is insignificant. It's the A that counts. However, `COLUMN($A$2)` is long for just `1`, meaning column No. 1, meaning A. Once you get your bearing in the formula you can replace `COLUMN($A$2)` with `1`.